# Javascript/JSON: Swap items in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, swap

I'm pretty new to Javascript, and want to swap the items of an array in an array. Example:

```
{
    "data": [
        [null, 1353064450],
        [null, 1353064460],
        [null, 1353064470],
        [null, 1353064480],
        [null, 1353064490]
        ],
    "label": "cpu"
}
```

should become:

```
{
    "data": [
        [1353064450, null],
        [1353064460, null],
        [1353064470, null],
        [1353064480, null],
        [1353064490, null]
        ],
    "label": "cpu"
}
```

I probably have to iterate through the array and create a new array? Any pointers would be great!

Comment: Have you tried with the phpjs.org please check. http://phpjs.org/functions/array_flip/

Comment: Why would you need that library when you have a perfectly good native method to do this.

Comment: No. It is not a library. It is a simple js code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With modern JS, you can just do `obj.data = obj.data.map(([x, y]) => [y, x])`.

Support across browsers might be patchy, so you should use a transpiler that turns this into ES5, at least for the near future.

**Original answer**:

Use the `Array.reverse` method:

```
var obj = {
    "data": [
        [null, 1353064450],
        [null, 1353064460],
        [null, 1353064470],
        [null, 1353064480],
        [null, 1353064490]
        ],
    "label": "cpu"
};
for(var i=0; i< obj.data.length; i++){
     obj.data[i].reverse();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fun way that will work in modern browsers *(e.g. IE9 and higher)*:

```
response.data.forEach(Function.call.bind([].reverse));
```

---

Or if you do this a lot where you need a `.call` method with its `this` value bound to a method that itself operates on a `this` value *(as above)*, you can make a reusable `.call` binder.

```
var callBind = Function.bind.bind(Function.call);

  // Then use it like this
response.data.forEach(callBind([].reverse));
```